# Incorrect filename when iterating through files

Tags: python

I want to add a character at the end of each line in all the files in a folder, so I've written some code in order to iterate through each file and add the desired change, however the output files have different filenames than the originals, below is the code that I've put together

```
import os
output = '/home/test/Playground/Python/filemodification/output/'
def modification():
       with open(files, 'r') as istr:
           with open(str(output) + str(files), 'w') as ostr:
               for line in istr:
                   line = line.rstrip('\n') + 'S'
                   print(line, file=ostr)

directory = '/home/test/Playground/Python/filemodification/input'
for files in os.scandir(directory):
       #print(files.path)
       print(files)
       #print(output)
       #print(type(files))
       modification()
```

Once I run the code I get the following filename

```
<DirEntry 'input.txt'>
```

and this is the original filename

```
input.txt
```

I know the issue is probably related with this

```
with open(str(output) + str(files), 'w') as ostr:
```

but I haven't found a way to perform this task differently

If someone could point me in the right direction or provide a code example that can acommplish this task it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You may wanna use `listdir()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`os.scandir`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) returns [**`os.DirEntry`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) objects. You can get their filename by accessing their `.name` attribute, or their full path through `.path`.

E.g.:

```
for entry in os.scandir(directory):
    print(entry.path)
```